# knockout.js doesn't work in chrome but works fine firefox

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

```
    $(function(){
        $("#herb_pinyin").autocomplete({source: "api_herbs.php"});

        $.extend(bindings, {
            ingredients: ko.observableArray(),
            newIngredient: {
                pinyin: ko.observable(""),
                dosage: ko.observable(""),
                dosageType: ko.observable("g")
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindings(bindings);

    });

    function addIngredient() {
        if (!bindings.newIngredient.pinyin()) return;
        bindings.ingredients.push({
            pinyin: bindings.newIngredient.pinyin(),
            dosage: bindings.newIngredient.dosage(),
            dosageType: bindings.newIngredient.dosageType(),
        });
        bindings.newIngredient.pinyin("");
        bindings.newIngredient.dosage("");
        bindings.newIngredient.dosageType("g"); 
        $("#herb_pinyin").focus();
    }
        <div data-bind="foreach:ingredients">
            <div>
            <span data-bind="text:pinyin"></span>,
            <span data-bind="text:dosage"></span><span data-bind="text:dosageType"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div data-bind="foreach:ingredients">
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:pinyin, attr:{name:'pinyin-'+$index()}" />
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:dosage, attr:{name:'dosage-'+$index()}" />
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:dosageType, attr:{name:'dtype-'+$index()}" />
  </div>
      <input name="herb_pinyin" type="text" id="herb_pinyin" placeholder="herb name in pinyin" size="30" data-bind="value:newIngredient.pinyin" />
      <input name="dosage" type="text" id="dosage" placeholder="enter amount" size="13" data-bind="value:newIngredient.dosage" />
      <select name="dosage_type" id="dosage_type" data-bind="value:newIngredient.dosageType" >
        <option value="g" selected="selected">g</option>
        <option value="pcs">pcs</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add" onclick="addIngredient()" />
```

add ingredient function button doesn't do anything in chrome and IE; works fine in firefox. any clues as to why it's not working? basically clikcing the add button will later on perform an update to mysql.

in the api_herbs.php i get herb list for autcomplete from database and put in json:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rsList))
    $results[] = $row->pinyin;

print json_encode($results);
```

I tried your suggestion of adding bindings.addIngredient = addIngredient; but that didn't have any noticeable effects.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: strange thing is that there are no errors in console.....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste all your code, it seems. For one, the element with ID 'herb_pinyin' is missing. Additionally, you included some of the JavaScript twice (which will produce an error because ko.applyBindings is called twice). I'll assume this is a copy-paste error :)

Without the full source, it's hard to say for sure what's wrong. However, I do notice that your addIngredient function is not on the viewmodel. Correct this by adding the following line before your call to ko.applyBindings:

```
bindings.addIngredient = addIngredient;
```

Let me know if that helped. If not, please add the missing source code.

**Edit:**
The problem was indeed (partially) that addIngredient wasn't on your viewmodel. I've created a JSFiddle based on your code that does work (tested in Chrome).

http://jsfiddle.net/YzLMq/

In addition to adding the addIngredient function to the viewmodel before applying bindings, I also changed the HTML on your add-button to use data-bind="click: addIngredient" instead of what you had there.

Comment: Updated my answer with a fix. Let me know if you still run into problems.

Comment: Did what you recommended but still no go...i noticed that once in a while it works but i could only add no more than 4 ingredients before add button stops working. Refreshing the page, I could add only 3 and sometimes 2 times. If I add something that is not part of the autocomplete list, it works fine. The problem seems to be if i add something on the autocomplete list. Maybe the way json and knockout not interacting properly?

Comment: I suppose it must indeed be the autocomplete that's throwing you off - the only part that isn't reproducable in the Fiddle. So the problem can be in either jQuery UI's autocomplete (assuming that's the one you use), or in the data you serve to the autocomplete itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment about it not working when you select from the autocomplete:

it could very well be that the autocomplete inserts a value through JavaScript when you select something from the autocomplete list. In that case, no event is fired that the field is updated, and Knockout won't KNOW there's a value in the field. This could be your problem.  To solve this, you have to hook into the events that the jQuery autocomplete fires, and update your knockout observable manually. See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

I think you need the 'select' event. So you get something like this:

```
$("#herb_pinyin").autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        bindings.newIngredient.pinyin($("#herb_pinyin").val());
    }
});
```

Haven't tested the above, but I hope you get the idea!